# How can I round up or down in C#?

Tags: c#, math

I have tried using *[Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round)* and *[MidpointRounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding)*. This does not appear to do what I need.

Example:

```
52.34567 rounded to 2 decimals UP   = 52.35
 1.183   rounded to 2 decimals DOWN =  1.18
```

Do I need to write a custom function?

Sometimes I need a number like 23.567 to round DOWN to 23.56.
In this scenario...

```
Math.Round(dec, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) gives 23.57
Math.Round(dec, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) gives 23.57
```

Decimals up to 9 decimal places could come out and need to be rounded to 1, 2, 3 or even 4 decimal places.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying by 100, round it, and divide by 100?

Comment: This appeared to work for me.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?  `Response.Write(Math.Round(52.34567, 2).ToString());`  Output: 52.35

Comment: Obviously he hasn't tried them, as it does exactly what he needs. He can even test it out himself: `Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(52.34567, 2));` and `Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.183, 2));`

Comment: Changed my answer to handle clarified requirement

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try using decimal.Round():

```
decimal.Round(x, 2)
```

Where `x` is your value and 2 is the number of decimals you wish to keep.

You can also specify whether .5 rounds up or down by passing third parameter:

```
decimal.Round(x, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

EDIT:

In light of the new requirement (i.e. that numbers are sometimes rounded down despite being greater than "halfway" to the next interval), you can try:

```
var pow = Math.Pow(10, numDigits);
var truncated = Math.Truncate(x*pow) / pow;
```

Truncate() lops off the non-integer portion of the decimal.  Note that `numDigits` above should be how many digits you want to KEEP, not the total number of decimals, etc.

Finally, if you want to force a round up (truncation really is a forced round-down), you would just add 1 to the result of the `Truncate()` call before dividing again.

Comment: Why not [Decimal.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round) (capital "D")?

Answer (score 34):

Try using `Math.Ceiling` (up) or `Math.Floor` (down). e.g `Math.Floor(1.8) == 1.`

Comment: Those are good function, however, they force the value to a whole number.  I need to maintain the decimals in many cases.

Comment: If you would like do it for decimals you can do it in that way: `Math.Floor(1.87*10)/10 == 1.8`

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you're using the `decimal` type for your numbers,

```
static class Rounding
{
    public static decimal RoundUp(decimal number, int places)
    {
        decimal factor = RoundFactor(places);
        number *= factor;
        number = Math.Ceiling(number);
        number /= factor;
        return number;
    }

    public static decimal RoundDown(decimal number, int places)
    {
        decimal factor = RoundFactor(places);
        number *= factor;
        number = Math.Floor(number);
        number /= factor;
        return number;
    }

    internal static decimal RoundFactor(int places)
    {
        decimal factor = 1m;

        if (places < 0)
        {
            places = -places;
            for (int i = 0; i < places; i++)
                factor /= 10m;
        }

        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < places; i++)
                factor *= 10m;
        }

        return factor;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Rounding.RoundDown(23.567, 2) prints 23.56
```

Comment: You can also easily modify this example to make Extension methods for the decimal type e.g.  public static decimal RoundDown(this decimal number, int places)

Answer (score 11):

For a shorter version of the accepted answer, here are the `RoundUp` and `RoundDown` functions that can be used:

```
public double RoundDown(double number, int decimalPlaces)
{
    return Math.Floor(number * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces)) / Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
}

public double RoundUp(double number, int decimalPlaces)
{
    return Math.Ceiling(number * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces)) / Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Complete code with result.

```
  double a = Math.Round(128.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

**Result is** 129

Answer (score 1):

The `Math` class gives you methods to use to round up and down, they are `Math.Ceiling()` and `Math.Floor()` respectively. They work like `Math.Round()`, but they have a particularity, they only receive a value and round them to only the entire part.

So you need to use `Math.Pow()` to multiply the value by 10 to the n-esimal units you need to round power and then you need to divide by the same multiplied value.

Is important that you note, that the input parameters of the `Math.Pow()` method are `double`, so you need to convert them to `double`.

For example:

> When you want to round up the value to 3 decimals (supposing value type is `decimal`):
>
> ```
> double decimalsNumber = 3;
> decimal valueToRound = 1.1835675M;
> // powerOfTen must be equal to 10^3 or 1000.
> double powerOfTen = Math.Pow(10, decimalsNumber);
> // rounded must be equal to Math.Ceiling(1.1835675 * 1000) / 1000
> decimal rounded = Math.Ceiling(valueToRound * (decimal)powerOfTen) / (decimal)powerOfTen;
>
>
> Result: rounded = 1.184
> ```
>
> When you want to round down the value to 3 decimals (supposing value type is `decimal`):
>
> ```
> double decimalsNumber = 3;
> decimal valueToRound = 1.1835675M;
> // powerOfTen must be equal to 10^3 or 1000.
> double powerOfTen = Math.Pow(10, decimalsNumber);
> // rounded must be equal to Math.Floor(1.1835675 * 1000) / 1000
> decimal rounded = Math.Floor(valueToRound * (decimal)powerOfTen) / (decimal)powerOfTen;
>
>
> Result: rounded = 1.183
> ```

To reference how to use them more specificaly and to get more information and  about both methods you can see these pages from the oficial MSDN Microsoft site:

[Math Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Math.Pow Method (Double, Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Math.Floor Method (Decimal)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Math.Floor Method (Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Math.Ceiling Method (Decimal)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz5da1c(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Math.Ceiling Method (Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
Math.Round(dec + 0.5m, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this custom rounding:

```
public int Round(double value)
{
    double decimalpoints = Math.Abs(value - Math.Floor(value));
    if (decimalpoints > 0.5)
        return (int)Math.Round(value);
    else
        return (int)Math.Floor(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the method of [Math.Round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round) or decimal.Round():

```
Math.Round(amt)
Math.Round(amt, Int32) and other overloading methods.

decimal.Round(amt)
decimal.Round(amt, 2) and other overloading methods.
```