# Rounding decimals to two decimal places in c#

Tags: c#, rounding

I want to round 54.5345 to 54.54 
that is if I have a third decimal place then i want to add 1 to the 2nd decimal place.

I have tried using math.round but it always rounds down if the third decimal is less than 5

Comment: That's how rounding actually works mathematically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482159/how-to-round-up-or-down-in-c

Comment: Please read the concept of rounding on wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding)

Comment: seriously .! I know how rounding works but I want to round up 54.5345 to 54.54 and not 54.53

Comment: What do you want to have happen if the number is negative? Does `-54.5345` get *less negative* and therefore *larger*, and go to `-54.53` or do you want its *absolute value* to get larger and go to `-54.54` ?

Comment: Its always going to be in positive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
d = Math.Ceiling(d * 100) / 100;
```

where d is your decimal.

Comment: What if the number is negative?

Comment: For my purpose its always going to Positive

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
      double a = Math.Round(-57.5345, 2);
```

This works for negative numbers too.

The way you are rounding off is not correct.

You can also refer:

[How do you round a number to two decimal places in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643280/rounding-bigdecimal-to-always-have-two-decimal-places?rq=1

Comment: please read the question again, I want to always round up the 2nd decimal if third decimal place exist