# How can I round up or down a double to one less decimal place than the input has in C#?

Tags: c#, rounding, calculation

I have two values and I want to round them like this. How can I do this for one less decimal place than the input has with math methods in C#?

100.67 -> 100.7 -- up

100.67 -> 100.6 -- down

50.563 -> 50.57 -- up

50.563 -> 50.56 -- down

I tried this code block, but it didn't work like I want. I don't want to give a precision for rounding. Whatever the decimal value is, I need to round it up or down.

```
public double RoundDown(double number, int decimalPlaces)
{
    return Math.Floor(number * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces)) / Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
}

public double RoundUp(double number, int decimalPlaces)
{
    return Math.Ceiling(number * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces)) / Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round up or down in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482159/how-to-round-up-or-down-in-c)

Comment: @zedge08 I think I understand that you are looking for a way to round to "one less decimal place than the input has"? If yes, please edit your question to clarify this, and highlight especially that you are looking for a solution where you don't have to manually give the precision. This would be a question that can be answered (although I may foreshadow that the answer is probably not quite what you are hoping for, since the oddities of floating-point-arithmetic makes this a much less trivial problem than you might realize so far).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to write a method to round up (or down) a double value of arbitrary precision by a single decimal position ?

Comment: @Alex yes you got it right but it is valid for every decimal position.

Comment: Some more insidious values are boundary ones like 100.65, 50.565, 100.05, and 50.005 (and depending on the underlying (machine) representation of them).

Comment: This question is discussed in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424253/how-should-i-proceed-if-my-re-open-vote-was-rejected-although-the-issues-are-fix)

Comment: [1/2] `c#` is not my *Area of Expertise* (I came here from the 'Meta' Thread), but I still find this Qt "unclear", with 1 Answer provided (based on several Assumptions that should be clearly defined in the Qt...). => "*I have two values*" is probably irrelevant, you want for any Input Value 2 Outputs, the `RoundUp` + `RoundDown` with `n*Dec -1`. // => Define where your Input Values come from: Do they always have [2-3] Decimals...?,

Comment: [2/2] ... or define those 2 Nb's. Can they be `100.33333333...` or `50.99999999....` (coming from a Fraction)...?, => can you *force* 4 or 6 Decimals...? (=> `100.3333` or  `50.9999` would *invalidate* @LWChris's Answer, etc...) :idea:

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of terminology, I want to define "rounding" a bit more rigorous here. "Rounding up x to n decimal places" will be called "Rounding up x to a precision of n places", and will more specifically mean "Finding the closest number greater than or equal to x that uses at most n places behind the decimal point." The "at most" part is actually important, because "rounding 10.9991 up to a precision of 3 places" will be "11".

Your question asks for a method that rounds to "one less decimal place than the input", specifically without the necessity to tell that method the precision the output is supposed to have. Therein lies a hidden problem: numbers using floating point representation according to [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

The number of decimal places used to store a number may not be what you would naturally expect. While the standard does a really good job, adding numbers with 2 decimal places may quickly result in a number with "infinite" decimal places. Consider [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GGRc0l):

```
var x = 0.0002f;
var x5 = 5 * x;
```

It may surprise you to learn that `x5` is not `0.001` but `0.0009999999`. Going to `double` from `float` helps in this case, but ultimately `double` will suffer from the same problem, just for different values.

So, what is your expectation for `RoundUp(x5)`? If the value was `0.001`, your expectation would be `0.01`. But what is the number of decimal places for `0.0009999999` which represents a fictional `0.0009...` with infinite decimal places? And even if we say `0.0009999999` was exactly equal to `0.00099999990` for the sake of argument, and thereby conclude it has 10 decimal places, then it rounding up to a precision of 9 places means rolling over the nines at the end until we arrive at `0.001`, not `0.01`.

Therefore, it is impossible to algorithmically safely determine "how many decimal places" a given floating point number has in base 10. Therefore you need to provide the desired precision to any function, which will lead you to the code you already have.